# Displaying elements from a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to display the elements of a dictionary but I'm having difficulties, when I try to display it shows the whole object, this is my code:

```
produtos = []
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def aviso():
 request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/snkrs#estoque")
 soup = bs4(request.text, "html.parser")
 links = soup.find_all("a", text="Comprar", class_="btn")
 for link in links:
  produtos.append(link["href"])
 print(produtos)
```

The problem here is that it displays everything in this format:

> ['https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-90-153-169-211-330199', ...]

How can I get only the link on this dictionary?

**Edit:**

I want to display it this way:

> 'https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-90-153-169-211-330199', ...

**I'm creating a bot for discord, I posted only the useful part of the code.**

Comment: `produtos.append(link["href"])` means you are starting off with a list and populating it with a dictionary result. If the length of links is greater than 1, you're going to get more than 1 link result populating in that list, so you need to decide how you best want to approach this. You can access the first link with `produtos[0]` for instance

Comment: What's wrong with that output? That's just the link.

Comment: @PeptideWitch Plus I want to get all the links, no square brackets [

Comment: @Barmar I want to get the links without the square brackets

Comment: Confusion would be avoided if you showed what you wanted the result to be.

Comment: @Barmar I want to be able to print the links, as a string, but without the square brackets, and with a comma, as I mentioned in the question, but without square brackets

Comment: You need to say that in the question, not a comment. It's not clear. When I read the question, I thought you meant that it was showing other items from the dictionary in addition to the `href`.

Comment: Show an example of the desired output, because saying it in words isn't always clear.

Comment: @Barmar I already edited

Comment: BTW, the dictionary is irrelevant to the question. You just want to know how to display a list of strings without the square brackets. It doesn't matter that the strings originally came from a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar Actually it's important that the links are in a dictionary, I'll use this variable at the front of my script

Comment: It's important for your application, but it has nothing to do with the specific problem you're having.

Comment: SO once again, the question linked as a duplicate of doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement. He wants quote around the final output

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the representations of the links, separated by comma:

```
print(", ".join(map(repr,produtos)))
```

`repr()` will put quotes around the link, and `", ".join()` will separate them with comma.

Comment: I need to get the link from the dictionary, because I need to get all the links, not one by one, and also because I'm going to use it later in my code

Comment: By the way, I declared the variable as global, I forgot to add the question

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comment above.

Answer (score 0):

To print the entries in **produtos** without the brackets, simply do `print(*produtos, sep=", ")`  In this case set **sep** to whatever you want to be the separator between the links

**EDIT**
To have quote around the final output

```
print(*("'{}'".format(item) for item in produtos), sep=', ')
```

Comment: This displays without the square brackets, the problem is that the links are not enclosed in quotes, and there is no comma, how can I fix this?

Comment: If you want comma as the *separator* then that's ```print(*produtos, sep=", ")``` as I said in my answer. Set **sep** to whatever you want to separate the links with

Comment: That's what I did, the problem is that the links are still not in quotation marks

Comment: It now display quotes, I updated my answer